# Is there a way to convert a list into a string?

Tags: python, string, list

```
import itertools as iter 
numbers = ['0', '1'] 
y = list(iter.product(numbers, repeat=2))
a = ''.join(y)
 
print(a)
```

When I try to convert y into a string, I join the string 'a' with y. But I keep getting the error "TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, tuple found"

Any solutions?

Comment: Note that importing `itertools` as `iter` probably isn't the best practice since it shadows the builtin [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter)

Comment: Please note that the code by @Daniel Hao does not "convert a list into a string", which is the subject line of the question, but rather converts tuples into strings and prints them, in a loop. You may want to update your question title.

Comment: Instead of printing the output, how can I add that to one string, e.g. make the string equal to '00011011'?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) returns an iterator of tuples, so you have to `join` *each* of the values in that list:

```py
import itertools

numbers = ['0', '1'] 
y = itertools.product(numbers, repeat=2)
# output of product
# <iterator>(('0', '0'), ('0', '1'), ('1', '0'), ('1', '1'))

a = [''.join(t) for t in y]
a
# ['00', '01', '10', '11']
```

Note you don't need to convert `y` to a list to use it in a comprehension.

If you want to make that into one string, you can then `join` again:

```py
''.join(a)
# 00011011
```

or as one operation

```
a = ''.join(''.join(t) for t in y)
```

Comment: You could use the more general "sequence", since the type of sequence isn't really important in this context.

Comment: Same idea.  Please see my earlier post - make `01` as binary string sequence.

Comment: @Barmar At least in Python terminology, sequences are something else and iterators (usually, including this one) aren't sequences.

Comment: @KellyBundy So what *is* the general word for anything like this, iterable? I'm pretty sure I've seen lots of documentation that uses sequence for this.

Comment: @Barmar Iterables is certainly correct, yes. As is iterator. List (what the answer said first) I'd say is really wrong, as in Python context that really makes people think of `list`. Sequence I guess is ok, as that's much less likely understood as  [this](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-sequence) and indeed Python's own documentation often (?) says it meaning something else.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `y` is a list of tuples, each of which contains two one-character strings.

If I'm understanding, I think what you want to do is this:

```py
import itertools as it
numbers = ['0', '1'] 
y = list(it.product(numbers, repeat=2))
a = ''.join(''.join(x) for x in y) 
print(a)
```

Output:

```
00011011
```

An alternative that produces the same result using the `chain()` function in itertools is:

```py
import itertools as it
numbers = ['0', '1'] 
y = list(it.product(numbers, repeat=2))
a = ''.join(it.chain(*y))
print(a)
```

Comment: @CJ-Programmer Do you need more help with your question? If you've got what you need now, please consider marking one of the answers "accepted".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what output you're looking for, put if you're going to use `itertools` I would keep the style functional:

```
import itertools 
from functools import reduce
numbers = ['0', '1'] 
y = itertools.product(numbers, repeat=2)
y = map(lambda x: ''.join(x), y)
y = reduce(lambda x, z: x + z, y)
print(y)
```